# Why must I do null check in C++?

Tags: c++, pointers, null-pointer

I want to know necessity of null check.

Sample code is following

```
#include <iostream>
bool twice( int* a )
{
    if( a == nullptr )
    {
        std::cout << "null" << std::endl;
        return true;
    }
    std::cout << *a << std::endl;
    *a *= 2;
    std::cout << *a << std::endl;
    return false;
}
int main()
{
    twice( nullptr );
    int v = 16;
    std::cout << v << std::endl;
    twice( &v );
    std::cout << v << std::endl;
}
```

This is output

```
null
16
16
32
32
```

I recognize that 'nullptr' is "the pointer that point out address zero of memory" or "Flag when reference of pointer variable is invalid".

---

Q1. address zero of memory is only one per real memory?

Q2. Can you reproduce "reference of pointer variable is invalid" on this code?

Q3. What kind of function does the pointer variable reference become invalid?

Sorry, my poor English.

Comment: It is not pointed to a particular part in memory. Which is why it will crash trying to use a null pointer.

Comment: If you change your function `twice()` to accept a reference rather than a pointer, then it is not necessary to do a null check. It is not possible for the caller to pass a reference to a non-existent object (`int` in your case). Yes, it is possible for the caller to do an operation with undefined behaviour to create and then pass an invalid reference (e.g. by dereferencing a null pointer, and passing that). But, if the caller has undefined behaviour, all bets are off anyway - your function cannot reliably detect such a case, or handle it safely. The onus is on the caller to not do that

Comment: A null check is not necessary if you can guarantee (based on your understanding of the program's overall logic) that the pointer will never be null (or if you're okay with invoking undefined behavior and probably crashing your program when it is null).

Answer (score 2):

I would recommend thinking about this in a different way. Rather thinking of a null pointer as "memory address zero," think of it as "this pointer does not actually point at anything."

With that mental model, there's a clearer reason why you need the null check. If you have a pointer that doesn't actually point at anything, then writing

```
*a  *=  2;
```

is a meaningless operation - there is no thing being pointed at by `a`, so dereferencing `a` to get an integer and then doubling that integer isn't a well-defined operation.

Internally, on most systems, yes `nullptr` is implemented as "a pointer to memory address zero, which is considered invalid on most operating systems," but I don't think that sheds much light on why this code needs the null check.

Comment: Just out of curiosity: You wrote _[...] memory address zero, which is considered invalid on most operating systems_; on which OS is it valid?

Comment: @nada I could imagine that some embedded OS somewhere with no memory protection mechanisms at all might have address 0 mapped to something. I don't know of any concrete OSes off the top of my head that do this, but it wouldn't surprise me if one exists.

Comment: thank you for fast your answer.  I understood roughly.  And is it better not to understand the null pointer with this code?  This is because the user must enter 'nullptr' to make the output 'null' with this code, but nobody enter 'nullptr'?  I have never developed a systems.  So I'm sorry, but I don't get it about Internal the system.  If you have some easy idea with null check, I want to know that.

Comment: @nada In the past, I once used SGI workstations with MIPS CPUs and SGI's OS called Irix. Long time, I was not aware that this was one of the platforms where access to NULL was possible without the usually expected seg-fault or bus-error. I had a bad awakening when we ported our code to PCs with Linux - we even didn't reach `main()`. ;-)

Answer (score 0):

Pointer is just the unsigned integer that points to memory address. ln some system having virtual memory, the first page of the memory will not be mapped to physical memory.so, when we are trying to read/write at null pointer address it causes segmentation fault/ page fault. However in some embedded devices we will not observe the segmentation fault issue as we could access the zero memory space

Irrespective of the os,To avoid application crash, adding null pointer check is good practice